# React hooks : 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to redirect my homepage to "/call" page based on a redux state. I can go to that component by typing the url manually but cant do it with a function. I tried "Redirect to", "history.push" but none of them worked for me. I cant solve the problem. Here is my code;

```
const Phone = ({ hidden, photoOpened, inCall }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(getContacts());
  let history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inCall.inCall) {
      history.push('/call')
    }
  }, [inCall]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getContacts());
  }, [])

  return (
    <div hidden={process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? !hidden : hidden} className={photoOpened ? "phone-container-rotate" : "phone-container"}>
      <div className="coque" />
      <Suspense fallback={<div className="animated fadeIn pt-1 text-center">Loading...</div>}>
        <HashRouter basename="/phone">
          <div
            className="phone-content"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${background})` }}
          >
            <HeaderBar />
            <BannerNotifications />
            <Switch>
              {routes.map((route, idx) => {
                return route.component ? (
                  <Route
                    key={idx}
                    path={route.path}
                    exact={route.exact}
                    render={props => <route.component {...props} />}
                  />
                ) : null;
              })}
            </Switch>
          </div>
          <Route component={BottomPhoneNavigator} />
        </HashRouter>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try and test for history existence of the history in your effect, also add it to dependency list

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (history && inCall.inCall) {
      history.push('/call')
    }
  }, [inCall, history]);
```

And important thing, your component using this hook must be within the `Router`, I see you'\re using `HashRouter` but as child of component using the hook.

Also if you're stuck to this structure, why wont you try to use `Redirect` within the Switch? This could work with some smart test so you wont end up in a loop:)

Comment: Page is not redirecting because history is always undefined

Comment: I can only assume that you have correctly setup react-router?

Comment: I can use route in that component. Just cant redirect

Comment: You can set `Route` as a child in this component tree, but you can't use `useHistory` here, I'm surprised with this setup, `Phone` component renders `HashRouter`, dont you have a `Router` somewhere above the tree hierarchy? I bet you dont, thus the `undefined`. As soon as I;ve wrapped component with a `Router` the history started to display values. IMO your application has a structural flaw which will bite you many times not just with the `useHistory` hook.

Answer (score 1):

To use history your Phone component should be inside router component